# Angular 7 Property 'size' is missing in type 'Response'

Tags: angular

So recently I updated my angular application, well I tried to. And this one error popped up and I don't know how to fix it. This error popped up in a function where the application downloads an Excel sheet and tries to open it in another window, this worked before the update. But after I updated to angular 7.1.0 It gave me the following error:

```
// the function related to this error is shown down below    
ERROR in src/app/adres.service.ts(87,28): error TS2322: Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.
      Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Blob'.
        Property 'size' is missing in type 'Response'
```

**Imports of adres service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule, ResponseContentType, Jsonp, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Mail } from './models/mail';
import { Klant } from './models/klant';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { GlobalsService } from './globals.service';
```

**The function**

```
  private downloadFile(data: Response) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

**Package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
```

the function I'm currently using worked until the 7.1.0 update. Can anybody tell what happened and how to fix it in this version?

Comment: Can you post the type definition of `Response`? According to the specs, it has to be `string | ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | Blob`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

Comment: If I go to the definition of Response it has these property types `string | Blob | Int8array to int32array | float32 and 64 array | dataview | arraybuffer | formData`

Comment: Is `Response` defined by you/your team? Or is it imported somewhere? Anyways, we would need to see the call to `downloadFile` that is causing the problem. The problem is quite clear: The content you pass to `downloadFile` is not the correct type for Blob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't exactly why or when it changed but I do know how to fix it. Just change `Response` to `any` like so:

```
  private downloadFile(data: any) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

Apperantly the way how you download files in angular changed. Since angular's lovely `any` type exists I thought it might fix the problem, and it did.

Comment: I assume it's due to an update in Typescript to match the javascript specifications. `any` is a great way to shoot yourself in the foot if you use it too much, so beware. Instead, try to understand what type you need and make it work

Comment: `any` is a fast solution. and I know what type I want and need as shown in my question. Typescript left me no choice

Comment: False, typescript left you a choice. You could define the type you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
private downloadFile(data: File) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
    // rest of the stuff
}
```

The type **File** did work for me to download a xlsx